# Great books on all different types of integration techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, book-recommendation

It's coming up to Christmas so I can ask to have all the books I can't afford from begrudging relatives! I'm really interested (mainly from looking at some of the answers cleo and other fantastic users!) in being able to approach integrals from a variety of different ways and learning how to tackle  non-elementary integrals.

I've gone over a lot of the standard techniques in my undergrad and this is just for a hobby, so don't want anything too 'heavy', just great explanations and a lot of questions to tackle. So far I've found Irresistible Integrals: Symbolics, Analysis and Experiments in the Evaluation of Integrals. Many thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. This does not quite answer your question, since it does not really have explicit techniques or questions to tackle. However, someone has taken the effort to prove many of the formulas in the famous Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. I imagine one could pick up many interesting techniques from reading these proofs. Here it is, if it happens to be of interest to you: http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/Table.html

Comment: @AWertheim Thanks - what a database!

Comment: Maybe a bit on the "heavy" side, but you can find some book suggestions here: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/extremely-hard-books-or-handouts-for-undergrad-studies

Comment: @AWertheim: "Someone" is Victor Moll, one of the author of the book "Irresistible Integrals" mentioned in the question.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you - I'll have a Google of some of the suggestions.

Comment: @HansLundmark: my apologies, I didn't mean to show any disrepect. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @AWertheim: No problem, I just thought it was a funny coincidence!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check out the book "Inside Interesting Integrals". The full title is

[Inside Interesting Integrals: A Collection of Sneaky Tricks, Sly Substitutions, and Numerous Other Stupendously Clever, Awesomely Wicked, and Devilishly Seductive Maneuvers for Computing Nearly 200 Perplexing Definite Integrals From Physics, Engineering, and Mathematics (Plus 60 Challenge Problems with Complete, Detailed Solutions).](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1493912763)

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't consider my book great or elementary but have a look at it

[Advanced integration techniques](https://zaidalyafeai.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/advanced-integration-techniques6.pdf)

Comment: The link is broken, do you have a new place one can find this book?

Comment: @spektr https://zaidalyafeai.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/advanced-integration-techniques6.pdf

Answer (score 7):

If after three years your interest in evaluating definite integrals has not waned, you may consider consulting the following texts:

1. *Improper Riemann integrals* by Ioannis M. Roussos (CRC Press, 2014).
2. *Solved problems: Gamma and beta functions, Legendre polynomials, Bessel functions* by Orin J. Farrel and Bertram Ross (MacMillian, 1963).
3. *Integration for engineers and scientists* by W. Squire (Elsevier, 1970).
4. *Integral evaluations using the gamma and beta functions and elliptical integrals in engineering: A self-study approach* by C. C. Maican (International Press, 2005).
5. *An introduction to sequences, series, and improper integrals* by O. E. Stanaitis (Holden-Day, Inc. 1967).

Answer (score 5):

1. This question has been asked and answered elsewhere, so check for similar threads here.  [Not meant to police the question, just FYI more answers there.]
2. Joseph Edwards Integral Calculus Treatise (old enough to be out of copyright and free pdfs available) has 1000+ pages of integration techniques and problems (many from the Cambridge Tripos).
3. Check out Zwillinger handbook or other handbooks of Integrals.  While not as fun as a problem list, you can learn from these books also.  Especially the ones that do more than just list formulas (like CRC tables) but give some derivation or other comments.

Comment: I appreciate point 1 but it is over 3 years since I posted this :P